# Finding an equation of a plane perpindicular to xy plane that intersects with a surface and has a directional derivate of zero at this point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm a bit new to 3D space and haven't had much practice with it. One question I'm working on says:

> A plane perpendicular to the x-y plane contains the point (3, 2, 2) on
>   the paraboloid $36z=4x^2+9y^2$. The cross-section of the paraboloid
>   created by this plane has slope 0 at this point. Find an equation of
>   the plane.

What I did was I solved for z explicitly, giving me:

$z=\frac{4}{36}x^2 + \frac{9}{36}y^2$

Then I found the partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ giving me:

$F_x = \frac{8}{36}x$

$F_y = \frac{18}{36}y$

Evaluating the partials at the point $(3,2,2)$ gives me: 
$F_x(3) = \frac{24}{34}$ 
$F_y(2) = 1$

Since it's given that the directional derivative at this point is zero, and that the plane is perpendicular to the x-y plane, I get the equation of the plane to be: 
$0=\frac{24}{34}(x-3) + (y-2)$

But the answer in the textbook says: 
$0=2(x-2)+3(y-2)$

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: I found your innocent mistake. $F_x=\frac8{36}x$ then you substitute $x=3$ and write $F_x=\frac{24}{34}$. Phewww.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Haha, it's been a while.

Comment: As I commented above. $F_x=\frac8{36}x$ at $x=3$ is $\frac{24}{\color{green}{36}}=\frac{2}{3}$. (and not $\frac{24}{\color{red}{34}}$) Your next formula should have been $0=\frac23(x-3)+(y-2)$. Multiplying by $3$ you could have been given the formula: $0=2(x-3)+3(y-2).$ I reached the same result in my answer. Your book solution is $0=2(x-\color{red}2)+3(y-2)$. Are you sure that the book solution is OK? If you are then I will reconsider my answer and will use your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our plane intersects the $xy$ plane in a straight line that goes throught the point $(3,2)$ and whose slope is unknown. Let $m$ be the slope. So, the equation of the intersection line is

$$y=mx-3m+2.$$

If we subtitute this $y(x)$ into the equation of the paraboloid we'll get the equation of the intersection of the plane and the paraboloid (projected to the $xz$ plane):

$$z=\frac19x^2+\frac14(mx-3m+2)^2.$$

The derivative of $z(x)$ with respect to $x$ equals $0$ at $x=3$ and $z=2$ because the tangent line in the projection looks the same as it does in the space. So

$$\frac{\operatorname dz}{\operatorname dx}_{\text{ at }x=3}=\left[\frac29x+\frac m2(mx-3m+2)\right]_{\text{ at }x=3}=0.$$
That is,

$$m=-\frac23.$$

Substituting this $m$ back to the straight line's equation we get

$$y=-\frac23x+4.$$

Multiplying both sides of the equation above by $3$ we get

$$3y+2x-12=0$$
or

$$3y-6+2x-6=0$$

or

$$3(y-2)+2(x-3)=0$$

which is the equation of the plane (at the same time) because the plain is perpendicular to the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Would it be possible to find the equation of the plane using partial derivatives? I appreciate your answer, but could you also point out what I'm doing incorrectly in my answer? We did a question like this similar in lecture, and the way we did it doesn't quite work out here.

Comment: @JohnNumbers: I have to leave my place right now. But I will be at your service soon. : ) I just wanted to give an easy answer...